# Magento 2: Class instance

Tags: magento2, event-observer, model, plugin

When i printed this `print_r(get_class($this->getOrder()));`
I got this class name

Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor

What does this actually mean ?
Where is this "`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor`" class ?

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interceptor classes are used in the implementation of the **plugin mechanism** in Magento 2.

These classes are automatically generated when you run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and you will find them in the **'generated'** folder of your Magento installation. In your particular case, this means you will find your physical file as **<magento_root_folder>/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Interceptor.php**.

Please read Alan Storm's answer on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124355/35330 for a detailed grasp on the term.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer, is their any way we can check from where did this Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Interceptor.php. is generated ?

Comment: hey there! Check the link form my answer it also mentions where and when the classes are generated, a brief extract "As for the actual generation, Magento handles this with a PHP autoloader. If a developer instantiates a class (or otherwise triggers a PHP autoload event with a class name (in a type hint, class_exists class, etc), and the composer based autoloader can't find the class file, a second registered autoloader `Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader::load` is triggered. "

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation

Comment: you are most welcome!